# Is there anyway to change SplashScreen in runtime ReactNative?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, splash-screen

I'm building a mobile application in react-native, i want it able to change logo and splashscreen in runtime.

I've known how to change logo, but i can't find any solution for changing SplashScreen.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add icon & splash in app.json file:

```
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "cover",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  }
```

Or if you want to add custom splash screen then use below module:
`npm i react-native-animated-splash-screen`

here is the module link for reference: [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash-screen)

Comment: u still need  to setup icon and splash screen in native folders, manifest and info.plist , right ?

Comment: Recently I'm using it in expo so, it's working perfectly fine without adding in other folders..

Comment: How to change  content of file app.json in runtime?

Comment: Please check this link to check all the functionalities.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash-screen